# Chat down with no custom error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, 500-server-error

Currently the chat.meta.stackoverflow.com site is down.

It is also giving the default ASP.Net error page, not the friendly custom one.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
```

Comment: Yeah, not even a lolcat :) Looking into it.

Comment: Man, I thought it was just me!  The fact that the "Server Error in '/'" page came up fooled DownForEveryoneOrJustMe.  And apparently their URLs confuse the Markdown parser, so:  http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/  EDIT: and now it __is__ correctly reporting that chat is down.  How odd.

Comment: @Popular Demand:http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ says "It's not just you" for me. EDIT: nevermind :p EDIT2: re following: agreed

Comment: @Tobias, yes, I retested after I posted my comment and just updated while you were commenting; thanks!  EDIT: we should keep posting replies in edits while the other person replies in a new comment simultaneously.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the bug report because the chat is down?  Or is the bug report because there is no custom error page?

Comment: @rchern Because the error page is missing.  Chat being back up would be nice, but I expect this because it's beta.

Comment: There *is* a custom error page - the error was too terminal for the error page to work...

Comment: @Marc Gravel That's some bad juju there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK; we're back up. Still investigating what happened, but the unicorns and the pixies have stopped fighting for long enough to serve requests instead.

Comment: Rrgh, refreshing takes you to the kitten page, because the URL still says error.  (Typing the URL in directly works, of course.)  @Marc, do you _need_ the pixies?  Can this be a unicorn-only operation?

Comment: Now I'm getting the lolcat error page.

Comment: @badp really? are you sure your browser isn't just left on the /error url? (the last *logged* error was a little while ago)

Comment: yeah, that was it.

Comment: @Popular - can't do it. The union got involved and everything.

Answer (score 4):

Reproduced, URL is then (FF3.6) http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/

[image: aspxerror]